# Windows doesn't boot after windows phone sdk installation

Tags: sdk, windows-phone-8.1, boot, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have HP ProBook 450 and i have just installed fresh version of windows 8.1 on it. I also installed full Visual Studio - Ultimate version with Windows Phone 8 SDK emulator. After installation i was asked to restart my computer.

I did so, and got stuck on loading screen. Windows never loaded. I did a research and found out it may be problem with GigaByte motherboard and USB 3.0 controller.

I tried disabling usb 3.0 in BIOS, but i was unable as there was no such option. I disabled it in control panel and still couldn't get into my home screen.

The only option to get to my home screen is by disabling HYPER-V in bios, which is not an option because i need it to run windows phone emulator.

There's nothing working for me.

Please help me. I'm desperate!!! I'll appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to check is if all your virtualization options are enabled in the bios and that your processer supports them. Hyper-V in Windows 8 requires SLAT to work. I've seen that same thing happen when I tried to enable Hyper-V on an old Core2Duo system. Unfortunately it might mean that your system is not compatible with Hyper-V in Windows 8.

Looking at the specs for that laptop if you aren't running an i7, i5 or i3 processor then Hyper-V won't work.